# Powershell Script to navigate files in SVN directory

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0

I need to navigate files from a SVN location instead of a windows location using PowerShell script, If I substitute windows path with SVN path it does not works, I have below working code for windows location:

```
function CheckPath($path)
{    
Test-Path $path -PathType Container
}

function Navigate()
{
$directory = "C:\Test" 
#Instead of above windows path I want to give SVN path as below: 
#https://svn.test.local/svn/Files/
$qscomponent="SomeValue"

if (CheckPath -path $directory)
{
Write-Host "Executing scripts from $directory"
Get-ChildItem $directory -Filter LTR*.sql | Foreach-Object -Process {              RunScript -comp $component -file $_.FullName   }
}
else
{
Write-Host "Invalid component: the path does not exist!"
}   
}
```

Comment: AFAIK, the FileSystem provider doesn't support browsing directories over HTTP.

Comment: Ok, Then how do I pick and execute files from SVN.
I do not want to check them out on windows location/directory.

Comment: Download them first, and then execute locally

Answer (score 0):

You can't execute anything that is on a remote SVN server. Any way of doing that will have to include downloading at least that file locally.

That said, to make this totally transparent, you could create script that depends on `svn ls` command.

One example is to change `prompt` function so that when you `cd` into some folder it will get the svn file list (ideally use proxy to `set-location`) but prompt is easier. Suppose you have `.svn` folder but no files (for this set [depth to `empty` when doing checkout](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.advanced.sparsedirs.html))

```
function prompt() {
    $lastCmd = h | select -Last 1 -expand CommandLine
    if ($lastCmd -match '^cd ') {
        $x = svn info
        if ($x -ne $null) {
            svn ls | % {Write-Host $_}
        }
    }

    "PS $pwd>"
}
```

This prompt function will list you all files on svn remote repository when you enter the folder. You could crete a simple powershell function that will download desired file and execute it (svn can checkout single files).

It will feel more Powershelly if you proxy `cd` or `ls` as you can then actually return array of items that you can pipe to for instance execution function, something like:

```
ls *.exe | execute
```

where `ls` is [proxied](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2011/03/01/proxy-functions-spice-up-your-powershell-core-cmdlets/) and executed inside the svn repository local path and `execute` uses svn checkout for piped files, perhaps to TEMP and executes them.